# How to set a watchOS minimum deployment target?

Tags: xcode, deployment, watchos

I just upgraded to Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8) and can now no longer run my app on the watch simulator. I get the error message

> Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm runs watchOS 5.3, which is lower than
>   XXX’s minimum deployment target. Change your project’s minimum
>   deployment target or upgrade Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm’s version of
>   watchOS.

However, the deployment target of the Watch target as well as the Watch Extension target are both set to 4.0. 4.0 is also the highest deployment target that I can set in Xcode.

I thought these were the minimum deployment targets, but maybe they are not.
Any suggestions?